# How to block navigation menu for admin in zend frame work navigation.ini file

Tags: php, zend-framework

am using zend framework 1.12 version for my development, in that for main navigation menu bar(side menu) i coded in navigation.ini file. I have two types of login (Admin, User). For admin only i have to show some extra menu. And for user also the same which can't see from admin page. For admin i done. But for user how to make menu bar in navigation.ini it should be hidden for admin.
my navigation.ini code is given below.

```
    [nav]

overview.uri = /overview
overview.label = "Dashboard"
overview.class = "nav_dashboard"
overview.resource = "overview"

admin.uri = /admin/user
admin.label = "User Manager"
admin.id = "nav_admin-index"
admin.resource = "admin"

admin.pages.user.uri = /admin/user
admin.pages.user.label = "Show Users"
admin.pages.user.id = "nav_admin-index"
admin.pages.user.resource = "admin"

admin.pages.import.uri = /overview/index/import
admin.pages.import.label = "Import Employees"
admin.pages.import.id = "nav_admin-index"
admin.pages.import.resource = "admin"

admin.pages.add.uri = /admin/user/add
admin.pages.add.label = "Add User"
admin.pages.add.id = "nav_admin-index"
admin.pages.add.resource = "admin"

;donateitem.uri = /donateitem
;donateitem.label = "Donate (Kind)"
;donateitem.id = "nav_donateitem-index"
;donateitem.resource = "donateitem"

;donateitem.pages.user.uri = /donateitem/index/
;donateitem.pages.user.label = "Show Items"
;donateitem.pages.user.id = "nav_donateitem-index"
;donateitem.pages.user.resource = "donateitem"

;donateitem.pages.add.uri = /donateitem/index/add
;donateitem.pages.add.label = "Donate Item"
;donateitem.pages.add.id = "nav_donateitem-index"
;donateitem.pages.add.resource = "donateitem"

donatecash.uri = /donatecash
donatecash.label = "Donate (Cash / In Kind)"
donatecash.id = "nav_donatecash-index"
donatecash.resource = "donatecash"

donatecash.pages.user.uri = /donatecash/index/
donatecash.pages.user.label = "Show Cash Donations"
donatecash.pages.user.id = "nav_donatecash-index"
donatecash.pages.user.resource = "donatecash"

donatecash.pages.item.uri = /donatecash/index/itemindex
donatecash.pages.item.label = "Show In Kind Donations"
donatecash.pages.item.id = "nav_donateitem-index"
donatecash.pages.item.resource = "donateitem"

donatecash.pages.add.uri = /donatecash/index/add
donatecash.pages.add.label = "Donate (Cash / In Kind)"
donatecash.pages.add.id = "nav_donatecash-index"
donatecash.pages.add.resource = "donatecash"

sellproduct.uri = /sellproduct
sellproduct.label = "Sell Prodcuts"
sellproduct.id = "nav_sellproduct-index"
sellproduct.resource = "sellproduct"

sellproduct.pages.user.uri = /sellproduct/index/
sellproduct.pages.user.label = "Show Products"
sellproduct.pages.user.id = "nav_sellproduct-index"
sellproduct.pages.user.resource = "sellproduct"

sellproduct.pages.add.uri = /sellproduct/index/add
sellproduct.pages.add.label = "Add Product"
sellproduct.pages.add.id = "nav_sellproduct-index"
sellproduct.pages.add.resource = "sellproduct"

buyproduct.uri = /buyproduct
buyproduct.label = "Buy Prodcuts"
buyproduct.id = "nav_buyproduct-index"
buyproduct.resource = "buyproduct"

buyproduct.pages.user.uri = /buyproduct/index/
buyproduct.pages.user.label = "Show Products"
buyproduct.pages.user.id = "nav_buyproduct-index"
buyproduct.pages.user.resource = "buyproduct"

buyproduct.pages.add.uri = /buyproduct/index/bought
buyproduct.pages.add.label = "Bought Products"
buyproduct.pages.add.id = "nav_bought-index"
buyproduct.pages.add.resource = "buyproduct"



report.uri = /admin/report
report.label = "Report"
report.id = "nav_admin-index"
report.resource = "admin"

report.pages.user.uri = /admin/report/report
report.pages.user.label = "Donate Cash Report"
report.pages.user.id = "nav_admin-index"
report.pages.user.resource = "admin"

report.pages.kind.uri = /admin/report/kind
report.pages.kind.label = "Donate Kind Report"
report.pages.kind.id = "nav_admin-index"
report.pages.kind.resource = "admin"

report.pages.sellproduct.uri = /admin/report/sellproduct
report.pages.sellproduct.label = "Buy & Sell Product Report"
report.pages.sellproduct.id = "nav_admin-index"
report.pages.sellproduct.resource = "admin"
```

In this donate item, donate cash should visible only for user. Can anyone tell how to do this. Am new in zend framework and dont know how to do this in navigation, Replies are appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Zend_ACL for access control?

Comment: yeah, but i am not able to see the connection between navigation and Zend_ACL

Comment: can you tell which file define those access control in navigation.ini

Comment: Check out this page from Zend: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.acl it has information on how to integrate zend_acl with zend_navigation.  The navigation object will utilize the ACL and show/hide nav links based on matching resource/privs if you set it up as such.